# What is "send bps" value in ss --info output?

Tags: linux, iproute2

If run `ss --info`, there is a `send #bps` in the output. I've found out that it's value is about twice bigger than real data flow speed.

From ss's source code, `send_bps` is:

```
s.send_bps = (double) info->tcpi_snd_cwnd *
(double)info->tcpi_snd_mss * 8000000. / rtt;
```

What does this value need for?
How can this help in diagnosis of network issues?

How to interpret this?